# Is there any type of penalty for killing/consuming civilians?

Tags: prototype-2

I am new to the series; never played prototype 1, though I probably should have. Oh well.

My question is, is there any kind of penalty (morality, ending, evolution, etc) to consuming an innocent civilian? Or am I free to just go wild?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There us no penalty to killing innocent bystanders (unlike the first game, where consuming them would deny you an achievement).

Go ahead and use them as the walking medkits that they are.

Comment: @Jonathan I would just like to add, that though there are no negative effects to consuming civilians, if the cops/military/"bad guys" see you doing it, the will attack you.

Comment: @Josefvz Naturally, but they will always attack you if you do anything sufficiently suspicious (and I think eating a civilian fits the bill nicely).